# Exception: The parameters (number) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Range.setValues

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

With the following function:

```
function updateCells() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var spreadsheetSummary = ss.getSheetByName('Summary');
  const range = spreadsheetSummary.getDataRange()
  const values = range.getDisplayValues()
  const transposeCheck = values[0].map((_, iCol) => values.map(row => row[iCol]).some(cell => cell))
  var countBoolean = transposeCheck.filter(Boolean).length
  var spreadsheetCommunityGroups = ss.getSheetByName('Community Groups');
  var cellValueCommunityGroups = spreadsheetCommunityGroups.getRange('A12').getValue();
  var summaryCommunityGroups = 'B'+countBoolean++
  spreadsheetSummary.getRange(summaryCommunityGroups).setValues(cellValueCommunityGroups);
}
```

I receive error

> Exception: The parameters (number) don't match the method signature
> for SpreadsheetApp.Range.setValues.

Comment: Clue: `setValues()` vs. `setValue()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this:

```
function updateCells() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var spreadsheetSummary = ss.getSheetByName('Summary');
  const range = spreadsheetSummary.getDataRange()
  const values = range.getDisplayValues()
  const transposeCheck = values[0].map((_, iCol) => values.map(row => row[iCol]).some(cell => cell))
  var countBoolean = transposeCheck.filter(Boolean).length + 1
  var spreadsheetCommunityGroups = ss.getSheetByName('Community Groups');
  var cellValueCommunityGroups = spreadsheetCommunityGroups.getRange('A12').getValue();
  var summaryCommunityGroups = 'B'+countBoolean
  spreadsheetSummary.getRange(summaryCommunityGroups).setValue(cellValueCommunityGroups);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Jacob, I need `var summaryCommunityGroups = 'B'+countBoolean++` - I want the data placed in the next column over, hence the ++.

Comment: That's why `var countBoolean = transposeCheck.filter(Boolean).length + 1`

Comment: @Steve not sure if my message can across....